# How to turn of auto-arrangement of XML widgets in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

After updating to new version of Android Studio the auto-format (CMD+ALT+L) has started to rearrange the order of the widgets in my layout XML's. I know how to set the settings for the arrangement of the attributes, but not sure how I toggle off the arrangement of the actual widgets.

Please help? :)

Comment: It's a common issue with the 3.5 upgrade. Check the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, will check it. :)